# Cambiar color de celda cabeceras de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

> Estoy batallando para cambiar el color de las cabeceras de arriba en que estoy fallando? ese es mi codigo

```
dgvDaily.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

[image: Imagen muestra del DataGridView]

Comment: Amigo, recuerda marcar la solución de tu problema si es que se resolvió o no tu duda. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, para cambiar el color de las cabeceras, te sugiero que crees un objeto de tipo `DataGridViewHeaderCell` y cuando vayas recorriendo tu DGV cuando lo dibujes/cargues le des un código similar a este:

```
{
    DataGridViewHeaderCell s = new DataGridViewHeaderCell();
    s.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Ahora, si no lo dibujas de forma dinámica, en las propiedades del DGV a tu costado derecho, debería aparecer la propiedad `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`, es ahí donde abres y editas los campos que necesites, en este caso es el **BackColor**.

Saludos!, no dudes en preguntar si te surgen dudas.

Comment: Tambien me sirve ese codigo para mas adelante, pero yo lo que necesito es cambiar el color donde estan los campos de sales order,customer,etc me cambia la fila de los registros nada mas

Comment: Amigo, al hacer click en el DGV en properties te aparece la propiedad `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`, ahí aparece el campo que necesitas cambiar, está en la respuesta.

Comment: @jorgetl2505 funcionó? recuerda que si funcionó esta solucion, la debes marcar como correcta con el tick verde. Tu duda puede ser la duda de alguien mas.